# Characters preceding the cursor

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to retrieve the index into a text area that the cursor is at using the keydown event?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

---

```
textarea.addEventListener('keydown', function (){
    console.log(textarea.selectionEnd); //The position of the cursor. If something is selected, then the position of the end of the selection.
}, false);
```

This function won't work for IE. In IE you'd have to use `document.createTextRange()`.

Comment: I know it works in Firefox, Safari. Does it work in IE?

Comment: @Akhil As I've said in the answer, no, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link for the implementation. You can call the `getCaret` function on your `keydown` event to get the index of the caret:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/263796/639960